# Unable to expect status in chakram when using .then in before()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, web-api-testing, chakram

I am using chakram to test API and whenever I am using a .then in a before(), I always get an error when testing the "it". I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I expect it has something to do with my returns.

```
describe('create group', function() {
    before('test', function() {
        return banana = chakram.request("POST", `${url}`, {headers, body}
         }).then(function (json) {
            test = json.body
         })
    })
    it("should return a 200 status when creating groups", function () {
        console.log(test)
        return expect(banana).to.have.status(201)
    })
})
```

The error returned is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the answer comes, you throw the non-answer to banana.

That's why the banana is hollow.

```
describe('create group', () => {
    let bananaResponse;
    before('test', () => {
        return chakram.request("POST", `${url}`, {headers, body}
         ).then((responseJson) => {
            bananaResponse = responseJson;
         })
    })
    it("should return a 200 status when creating groups", () => {
        console.log(bananaResponse.body);
        return expect(bananaResponse).to.have.status(201);
    })
})
```

You can try it.